# Spring Data query method with IN keyword using a List of enums as parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm using a Spring Data JPA (4.3.5) repository and a query method using IN keyword clause with a `List<Enum>` field as parameter. Problem is that it's **not working as I expect**.

Given an entity like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "R_REPRESENTACIO")
public class Representacio {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Estat estat;   

    ...
    //getters and setters
    ...
}
```

With that SQL declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE R_REPRESENTACIO (
  UUID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
  ...
  ESTAT VARCHAR2(255) NULL,
  ...
);
```

`Estat` is an Enum class like:

```
public enum Estat {
        VALIDA,
        PENDENT_VALIDACIO,
        PENDENT_DOCUMENTACIO,
        ...
}
```

And a JPA repository like:

```
public interface RepresentacioRepository extends JpaRepository<Representacio, Long> {
    List<Representacio> findAllByEstatIn(List<Estat> estats);
}
```

When I run (integration test class):

```
List<Estat> estats = 
  Arrays.asList(Estat.VALIDA,Estat.PENDENT_DOCUMENTACIO,Estat.PENDENT_VALIDACIO);
List<cat.aoc.representa.domain.entity.representacio.Representacio> allByEstatIn = representacioRepository.findAllByEstatIn(estats);
```

SQL generated is (in an in memory H2 DB):

```
2018-08-01 12:30:48.534--ServerSession(1175154004)--Connection(384887832)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT UUID, .... FROM R_REPRESENTACIO WHERE (ESTAT IN ((?,?,?)))
    bind => [VALIDA, PENDENT_DOCUMENTACIO, PENDENT_VALIDACIO]
```

No SQL exception is thrown and zero results are returned.
But this SHOULD return 1 result as this (equivalent) SQL returns:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM R_REPRESENTACIO WHERE ESTAT IN ('VALIDA','PENDENT_DOCUMENTACIO','PENDENT_VALIDACIO');

COUNT(*)
----------
         1
```

The unique difference I'm able to see is how i wrap the IN clause arguments between '' (that column is a VARCHAR).

I don't know why generated SQL from the JPA repository is not returning results.
(I've also tried `findAllByEstatIsIn(List<Estat> estats)` with same zero results returned).

Any suggestion/explanation?

*PS: Workarounded (not happy with) using*

```
List<Representacio> findAllByEstatOrEstatOrEstat(Estat estat, Estat estat2, Estat estat3);
```

*but that is uggly and wrong in many ways...*

Comment: As you state `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` the columns are varchars, but your param is a List of Enums. Have you tried to use a list of Strings instead?

Comment: yes, tried a repository method like findAllByEstatIn(List<String> estats) and running repo.findAllByEstatIn(Arrays.asList("VALIDA", "PENDENT_VALIDACIO"...)) but throws java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum

Comment: Have you tried then to write a query on your own? `@Query("select r FROM Representacio r where r.estat in :estats")`

Comment: What if you skip "All" and use `List<Representacio> findByEstatIn(List<Estat> estats)` ?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic I wish understand why or how IN clause works and avoid wrtiting as much sql as I can but your solution in this case is simple and works as I expect. Your solution works fine!

Comment: @StanislavL that doesn't work either

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ? if yes, could you please post the solution ? I've been fighting with this issue for hours :(

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple with the spring data JPA and JPQL:

```
@Repository
public interface RepresentacioRepository extends JpaRepository<Representacio, Long> {

    @Query("select r from Representacio r where r.estat in :estat2")
    List<Representacio> findByEnumEstat(@Param("estat2") List<Estat> estatList);
}
```

Comment: I was interested about knowing why or how the IN clause works in query methods with a List of Enums, but as @mrkernelpanic commented in the question, this solution solves muy use case

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a parameter with type `List<String>` and adding the converter `String -> Enum` so Spring will be able to convert that. So, basically:

1. `List<Representacio> findByEstatIn(List<String> estats);`
  2.

```java
@Configuration
public class ConverterConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  private EstatsConverter estatsConverter;

  @Override
  public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
    conversionService.addConverter(estatsConverter);

    super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
  }
```

  3.

```java
@Component
public class EstatsConverter implements Converter<String, Estat> {

    @Override
    public Estat convert(String source) {
        return Estat.fromString(source);
    }
}
```

I have no idea if that's gonna work, but I remember doing something similar, only in MongoDB. Let me know if you try that.

Comment: I like your aproach BUT I'm not using a REST repository but JpaRepository and can't use the RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter  class. I've been looking for a similar solution for JpaReposotory but I'm not finding how...